# Can't spawn "WinSCP.com in Perl

Tags: perl, batch-file

```
system("WinSCP.com /console /script=$scpConfig /parameter=<list parameters> ) == 0  or die "Error transfering file $fileToSend to destination Plateform ";

Can't spawn "WinSCP.com /console /script=$scpConfig  /parameter=<list parameters> 
11:27:13 :      [ERROR]  Error captured :  Error transfering file xxx.tar.gz
```

I type the same command on a DOS windows an can transfer my file via scp , meanwhile when I use the system command I've got this error:

```
Can't spawn "WinSCP.com /console /script=$scpConfig  /parameter=<list parameters>
```

Can someone help me about this ?

Comment: Please can you paste your actual code in, as currently above you are missing a " mark or 2. PS, are you sure winscp.com is in the path perl can see?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables, it seems the *.com file is for console operation only whereas *.exe is for both GUI and console, have you tried using the *.exe?

Comment: @drnewman, I think you have the answer. Write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables, it seems the *.com file is for console operation only whereas *.exe is for both GUI and console, have you tried using the *.exe?

Comment: Yes I want to execute WinSCP.com because its a batch operation so I don't need the ui interface ...

Comment: According the the documentation the *.exe does both, but the *.com also allows I/O redirection, is this something you need?